# When you want to finish your MainActivity, how to clear singleTask LaunchMode Activity in your Stack?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have a question:  I need a singleTask Activity.

It is a webViewActivity, I just load a URL.
But when you close it, it must not close: when you come back, the webViewActivity should show the history info!

So, I implemented it just to set the webViewActivity LaunchMode as "SingleTask".

It resolves the problem!

In my MainActivity, I just want to close the current app.
But, I can't do it: it always shows the webViewActivity.

When you click the back key, it will show the MainActivity.
But you can't close the app!

How to resolve this problem?

could you help me? Thank you very much!

I even used `System.exit(0);`
But it doesn't work well!

Comment: I resolve it by this way, you can follow me:

Comment: When  you invoke finish(), you can do it in this way:

Comment: finish();
ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this);

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this question by this way:

when you close your current activity, you can do in this way

```
finish();
ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(this);
```

Let me see resource:

```
/**
 * Finish this activity, and tries to finish all activities immediately below it
 * in the current task that have the same affinity.
 *
 * <p>On Android 4.1+ calling this method will call through to the native version of this
 * method. For other platforms {@link Activity#finish()} will be called instead.</p>
 */
public static void finishAffinity(Activity activity) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        ActivityCompatJB.finishAffinity(activity);
    } else {
        activity.finish();
    }
}
```

we can this this method. It is finish all activity in your JVM.

Comment: Android doesn't use JVM. It uses Dalvik.